# Survey Add New Question Type (Selection Option Field) Odoo 15

Tags: python, odoo

I would like to add a new question type to the survey: a Selection field(selection_option)
appears in the front as a selection field type with its options. I have added a new question type to the model (survey.question) and store the options in the suggested_answer_ids everything is good in the back but
when I am trying to test the survey and answer the question after selecting an option from the front and submit the answer, nothing get stored in the DB even thoug I have overrided the save_lines() and _save_line_choice in survey.user_input model. What elese should I do to get the answers stored In the back. Here is my code:

```
class SurveyQuestion(models.Model):

    _inherit = "survey.question"

    question_type = fields.Selection(
        selection_add=[("selection_option", "Dropdown Menu")]
    )


class SurveyUserInput(models.Model):

    _inherit = "survey.user_input"


    def save_lines(self, question, answer, comment=None):
        """ Save answers to questions, depending on question type

            If an answer already exists for question and user_input_id, it will be
            overwritten (or deleted for 'choice' questions) (in order to maintain data consistency).
        """
        old_answers = self.env['survey.user_input.line'].search([
            ('user_input_id', '=', self.id),
            ('question_id', '=', question.id)
        ])

        if question.question_type in ['char_box', 'text_box', 'numerical_box', 'date', 'datetime']:
            self._save_line_simple_answer(question, old_answers, answer)
            if question.save_as_email and answer:
                self.write({'email': answer})
            if question.save_as_nickname and answer:
                self.write({'nickname': answer})

        elif question.question_type in ['simple_choice','selection_option', 'multiple_choice']:
            self._save_line_choice(question, old_answers, answer, comment)
        elif question.question_type == 'matrix':
            self._save_line_matrix(question, old_answers, answer, comment)
        else:
            raise AttributeError(question.question_type + ": This type of question has no saving function")




    def _save_line_choice(self, question, old_answers, answers, comment):
        if not (isinstance(answers, list)):
            answers = [answers]

        if not answers:
            # add a False answer to force saving a skipped line
            # this will make this question correctly considered as skipped in statistics
            answers = [False]

        vals_list = []

        if question.question_type == 'simple_choice':
            if not question.comment_count_as_answer or not question.comments_allowed or not comment:
                vals_list = [self._get_line_answer_values(question, answer, 'suggestion') for answer in answers]
        if question.question_type == 'selection_option':
            if not question.comment_count_as_answer or not question.comments_allowed or not comment:
                vals_list = [self._get_line_answer_values(question, answer, 'suggestion') for answer in answers]
        elif question.question_type == 'multiple_choice':
            vals_list = [self._get_line_answer_values(question, answer, 'suggestion') for answer in answers]

        if comment:
            vals_list.append(self._get_line_comment_values(question, comment))

        old_answers.sudo().unlink()
        return self.env['survey.user_input.line'].create(vals_list)
```

the template:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwNc8.png)

I have tried to test the survey, select an option and send the answers but the data of this selection field allways empty, I want it store my selection in the back.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have added the 'suggested_answer_ids' field to the survey.user_input.line model, this way:

```py
suggested_answer_ids = fields.Many2many('survey.question.answer', string='Suggested Answers')
```

Modify the _save_line_choice method in the SurveyUserInput model this way:

```py
   
def _save_line_choice(self, question, old_answers, answers, comment):
    if not isinstance(answers, list):
        answers = [answers]

    if not answers:
        answers = [False]

    vals_list = []

    if question.question_type == 'simple_choice' or question.question_type == 'selection_option':
        if not question.comment_count_as_answer or not question.comments_allowed or not comment:
            vals_list = [self._get_line_answer_values(question, answer, 'suggested_answer') for answer in answers]
    elif question.question_type == 'multiple_choice':
        vals_list = [self._get_line_answer_values(question, answer, 'suggested_answer') for answer in answers]

    if comment:
        vals_list.append(self._get_line_comment_values(question, comment))

    old_answers.sudo().unlink()
    return self.env['survey.user_input.line'].create(vals_list)
```